# Perl: adding a string to $_ is producing strange results

Tags: string, perl

I wrote a super simple script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
 use strict;
 open (F, "<ids.txt") || die "fail: $!\n";
 my @ids = <F>;
 foreach my $string (@ids) {
 chomp($string);
 print "$string\n";
 }
 close F;
```

This is producing an expected output of all the contents of ids.txt:

hello

world

these

annoying

sourcecode

lines

Now I want to add a file-extension: .txt for every line. This line should do the trick:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
 use strict;
 open (F, "<ids.txt") || die "fail: $!\n";
 my @ids = <F>;
 foreach my $string (@ids) {
 chomp($string);
 $string .= ".txt";
 print "$string\n";
 }
 close F;
```

But the result is as follows:

.txto

.txtd

.txte

.txtying

.txtcecode

Instead of appending ".txt" to my lines, the first 4 letters of my string will be replaced by ".txt" Since I want to check if some files exist, I need the full filename with extension.

I have tried to chop, chomp, to substitute (s/\n//), joins and whatever. But the result is still a replacement instead of an append.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: On what platform are you running this, and what type of end-of-line (CR, CRLF?) does your file have?

Comment: +1 Interesting and tricky question.  See my answer for the solution

Answer (score 15):

Chomp does not remove BOTH `\r` and `\n` if the file has DOS line endings and you are running on Linux/Unix.

What you are seeing is actually the original string, a carriage return, and the extension, which *overwrites* the first 4 characters on the display.

If the incoming file has DOS/Windows line endings you must remove both:

```
s/\R+$//
```

Comment: Thats the trick! This explains why its working in windows xp environment! I have never dealt with \r ! But now I know, many thanks!

Comment: Um no. chomp() always removes whatever the value of $/ is. On DOS/Windows chomp() should be \r\n. Now if the file was created on Windows and then moved to a *nix box then that could be an issue. Still it shouldn't be overwriting anything based on his code.

Comment: @Cfreak: You are correct but he's obviously working cross-platform.  And also by _overwrite_ I meant _on the display_, not in memory.  On a unix system try `print "abcd\rxyz\n"` -- the result will be `xyzd`.

Comment: @Jim - you're right I see it now. Damn windows line endings :)

Comment: `s/\R+\z//` is what you want.

Comment: @tchrist: nice. That must be a recent (in the last few years) addition.  I used to a lot of Perl but not since about '07.

Comment: @Cfreak: Are you sure `$/` is `"\r\n"` on DOS and Windows?  I think line endings are translated to just `"\n"` on input, and back again on output.  That's the main difference between text and binary modes.

Comment: @Cfreak, Keith Thompson is 100% right. `$/` is `"\n"` on Windows. Perl adds a `:crlf` layer by default which converts CRLF->LF on read and LF->CRLF on write, so there's no \r for chomp to remove.

Answer (score 1):

A useful debugging technique when you are not quite sure why your data is getting set to what it is is to dump it with Data::Dumper:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper ();
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; # important to be able to actually see differences in whitespace, etc

open (F, "<ids.txt") || die "fail: $!\n";
my @ids = <F>;
foreach my $string (@ids) {
    chomp($string);
    print "$string\n";
    print Data::Dumper::Dumper( { 'string' => $string } );
}
close F;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
foreach my $string (@ids) {
  chomp($string);
  print $string.".txt\n";
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with your code though. these results are strange